# empty document error: scikit learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to fit SVM model for text classification but the line `x = text_clf_svm.fit(file_name, target_file)` is giving error. I tried various ways but could not solve it.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np


count_vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words=None, input='file')
file_name = open('./svmtest.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()
target_file = open('./target.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()

file_name = [StringIO(x) for x in file_name]
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(file_name)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
text_clf_svm = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words=None, 
input='file')),
                  ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                  ('clf-svm', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2',
                                        alpha=1e-3, n_iter=5, 
              random_state=42)),
          ])
 x = text_clf_svm.fit(file_name, target_file)
```

Python error traceback:

```
  File "/Users/aravind/PycharmProjects/PycharmProjects!/minorproject/src/svmClassifier.py", line 27, in <module>
x = text_clf_svm.fit(file_name, target_file)
File "/Users/aravind/venv/PycharmProjects!/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 248, in fit
Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
File "/Users/aravind/venv/PycharmProjects!/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 213, in _fit
 **fit_params_steps[name])
 File "/Users/aravind/venv/PycharmProjects!/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/memory.py", line 362, in __call__
return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/aravind/venv/PycharmProjects!/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 581, in _fit_transform_one
res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
File "/Users/aravind/venv/PycharmProjects!/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 869, in 
fit_transform
  self.fixed_vocabulary_)
File "/Users/aravind/venv/PycharmProjects!/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 811, in _count_vocab
raise ValueError("empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only"
ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop 
 words
```

My svmtest.txt contents:

```
train is so bad it is very dirty

great and awesome train
```

My target.txt contents:

```
0

1
```

I am using this simple data for test purpose. I am getting the above error. I am not sure what is the problem.

Comment: both answers helped in some way but i cannot accept both -_-.thanks a ton for both !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

- You only give two sentences in your input data. I can only assume that's not actually the case, but just in case it bears mentioning that words with a high document frequency might get considered "stop words". E.g., since "train" appears in both of your sentences above, it has a document frequency of 1.0, and thus would get ignored by your vectorizer. If you have a reasonably sized data set, this shouldn't be an issue.
- Consider using a standard stopwords dictionary in your vectorizer: `('vect', CountVectorizer(stopwords='english'))`. The default value of `None` is NOT equivalent to `no stop words`, rather it means "make your best guess". If you want there to be no stop words, use `stop_words=[]` instead.
- It's not clear whether the file you give is supposed to be a list of file names, which contain your data, or a list of strings, which is your data. Certainly, there's no call to convert the strings into `StringIO` objects.
- Either use the input data's file name and use `input='filename'`, or load it into memory and use `input='content'`. Converting them into `StringIO` objects just to use `input='file'` doesn't make sense.

Consider the following version of your code (I opted to use `input='filename'`, but adjust if desired):

```
file_name = './svmtest.txt'
targets = [int(line.strip()) for line in open('./target.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()]

text_clf_svm = Pipeline([
    # consider using stop_words='english'
    ('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words=None, input='filename')),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf-svm', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2', alpha=1e-3, n_iter=5, random_state=42)),
])
text_clf_svm.fit(file_name, targets)
x = text_clf_svm.predict(file_name)
```

Comment: But When I used your code I got an error saying SGDClassifier does't have any fit_predict attribute

Comment: @aravindreddy try to `fit` and `predict` separately (see edited code). Seems like SGDClassifier has `fit` and `predict` but not `fit_predict`.

Answer (score 1):

In line

`count_vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words=None, input='file')`

you set `input` parameter to 'file'. From docs

`If ‘file’, the sequence items must have a ‘read’ method (file-like object) that is called to fetch the bytes in memory.`

You can:
1. Pass to `fit_transform` method file object

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words=None, input='file')
file_name = open('./svmtest.txt', 'r')
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(file_name)
```

2. Use 'content' option

```py
count_vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words=None, input='content')
file_name = open('./svmtest.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()
target_file = open('./target.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()
file_name = [StringIO(x) for x in file_name]
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(file_name)
```

Comment: Additionally, he's creating new vectorizers in his pipeline instead of using the ones he already fit to his data. You should add a bullet to fix that

Comment: @scnerd Agree. But code contains so many issues, that easier just rewrite it from scratch, than describe and fix it all.